# How to know if a IDisposable was disposed?

Tags: .net, idisposable

How to know if a IDisposable object was disposed?

---

***Reason:***
I have a collection of `GraphicsPath`(`IDisposable`) that I use `OnMouseMove`.

Sometimes I clear the collection and dispose objects, and refill it again.

I build my Paths with a small number(2-10) of points, but sometimes I see that paths in collection have hundreds and thousands of points, that is impossible. I thought maybe paths was disposed when I reach this code... *related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959932/gdi-path-widen-region-isvisible-freezes-the-application)*

Comment: You shouldn't need to know this as a correct implementation of IDisposable must permit multiple calls to Dispose.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: So what? Once called, the object is disposed, so if one more *Dispose* call does not throw an exception, that does not mean that the object wasn't actually disposed, and can't be used anymore in "normal" way.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there's no way to know if `Dispose` has been called on a disposable object . However, some types, such as the WinForms `Control` type, do expose an [`IsDisposed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx) property or similar.

Since the client code is expected to deterministically control the 'lifetime' of the disposable object in the first place (disposed objects should *typically* be made unreachable pretty quickly, it's unlikely one would want to dispose of something *yet* hold onto a reference to it for long), it's uncommon to need this functionality.

Code such as the following quite possibly needs a change in design:

```
if(!myDisposable.IsDisposed)
   myDisposable.DoSomething();
```

Of course, if you really need this feature and the type doesn't provide it, you could manually implement it  yourself. For example, you could wrap it in a `class DisposableWrapper<T> : IDisposable where T : Disposable` that exposes an `IsDisposed` property *and* expects you to dispose the wrapped object through the wrapper's `Dispose` method, which does the relevant bookkeeping.

Comment: Ani, could you comment my edit? As my GraphicsPath collection is used in Paint or/and Mouse events, I have no really control of WHEN that pahts will be used, before, or after its disposal and recreation..

Comment: @serhio: I don't understand why you need to keep references to the disposed objects.

Comment: @ani: say, I draw Earth and Sun (2 circles), so, I have always 2 paths("earth") and paths("sun"). Sometimes Earth or Sun goes outside the screen, so I dispose the respective path. But when OnMouseMove I have a sun path under the mouse I should write a message "SUN", when I have Eearth, I should write EARTH. As example. I keep the paths collection always, just want to know if paths("Sun") was disposed do not test the mouse hit on it.

Comment: @serhio: I really think you're using the disposal of an object to represent something it shouldn't be used to represent. Why are you even bothering with disposing it? A performance optimization?

Comment: @Ani: in GDI is used to dispose graphic objects after its utilization. Pens, Paths, Brushes etc should be disposed. When Sun is no more on the screen, I dispose its path. Imagine not only earth and Sun, but all the galaxy I should represent.

Comment: @serhio: "dispose graphic objects after its utilization". That is correct. What would you want to *hold onto an object after its utilization*? You just need a reference to its `PathData`, which is not a disposable - its just an array of coordinates.

Comment: @Ani: When user moves the mouse, I "foreach" paths test if they don't contains my point. Once an path found, I write the respective message. I need a path I build a region from, and if Region.IsVisible(MousePoint) then write message.

Comment: @serhio: Your decision whether or not to dispose an object shouldn't generally be motivated by whether its position is on the screen.  You should either consistently keep the object around, or you should dispose and regenerate it every time you draw it.  If for performance reasons you need to dispose objects which happen to be off screen, you should probably null out the object references when you dispose them.  To facilitate this, it's helpful to have a Zap() routine that accepts a generic IDisposable by reference, uses Interlocked.Exchange to null it, and disposes it if it wasn't null.

Comment: @serhio: Along with this, you may want to code a factory method which accepts an object by reference and, if it's null, sets it to a new object (possibly using Interlocked.CompareExchange).

Comment: @Ani: One curious case where it may be useful to hold onto something after disposing of it is with Font objects.  Setting the Font property of a control seems to create a snapshot of the Font's attributes, without regard for whether the passed-in Font is disposed or not.  I'm not sure what the pros and cons are of disposing of a font which will only be used to set the Font property of other controls.

Answer (score 0):

Disposed is just a method. Without adding flags like `wasDisposed` it is impossoble to know.